# How can i make image with php 7.2 and pdo_informix in Docker?

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, informix, pecl

I am trying to create an image in docker with apache2, php7.2 with pdo_informix, but I have not been successful, I just do not see the extension enabled and I do not know if I'm doing a wrong step.

I share what I have so far in the following repository:
[here](https://github.com/Andresferreira3191/Docker-php-informix)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ibmcom/informix-developer-database
USER root
RUN sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
RUN sudo apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN sudo apt-get install git nodejs npm composer nano tree vim curl ftp -y
ENV TZ=America/Bogota
ENV LICENSE=accept
RUN sudo apt-get -y install apache2
RUN sudo apt-get install -y \
        php \
        php-bz2 \
        php-cgi \
        php-cli \
        php-common \
        php-curl \
        php-dev \
        php-enchant \
        php-fpm \
        php-gd \
        php-gmp \
        php-imap \
        php-interbase \
        php-intl \
        php-json \
        php-ldap \
        php-mbstring \
        php-mysql \
        php-odbc \
        php-opcache \
        php-pgsql \
        php-phpdbg \
        php-pspell \
        php-readline \
        php-recode \
        php-soap \
        php-snmp \
        php-sqlite3 \
        php-sybase \
        php-tidy \
        php-xmlrpc \
        php-xsl \
        php-zip
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade

VOLUME /var/www/html

COPY  index.php /var/www/html

ENV INFORMIXDIR /opt/ibm/informix
ENV PATH $INFORMIXDIR/bin:$PATH

COPY scripts/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3.tgz /tmp
COPY scripts/install-informixpdo.sh /tmp
RUN sudo sh /tmp/install-informixpdo.sh

#Informix environment variables for Apache
COPY scripts/envvars.sh /tmp
RUN sudo sh /tmp/envvars.sh
RUN echo "extension=pdo_informix.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini
RUN sudo echo "sqlexec  9088/tcp\nsqlexec-ssl  9089/tcp" >> /etc/services

EXPOSE 80
```

**install-informixpdo.sh:**

```
PDO_DIRECTORY=PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3
PDO_FILENAME=$PDO_DIRECTORY.tgz

TMPDIR=/tmp
tar  -xvf $TMPDIR/$PDO_FILENAME  -C $TMPDIR/
cd  $TMPDIR/$PDO_DIRECTORY
phpize  &&  ./configure  && make  &&  make install

rm -r $TMPDIR/*
```

**envvars.sh:**

```
echo "INFORMIXDIR=/opt/ibm/informix
export INFORMIXDIR
DB_LOCALE=es_es.8859-1
export DB_LOCALE
" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Comment: Can you give more details, including relevant code _in the question_, about what doesn't work?  The SO Help Center has some more hints on [ask].

Comment: Hello David, thank you for answering, in the repository is the Dockerfile used to create the image.: https://github.com/Andresferreira3191/Docker-php-informix. The problem I have is that the extension pdo_informix is not enabled and I do not know what happened, I'm doing badly.

Comment: Please post all relevant info (and updates) directly in your question (so also the code you only linked), since links can change (here you delete the github project) and thus don't benefit others with the same problem.

Comment: Now update, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your dockerfile script and found some errors. The docker build output did show traces on unpacking and compiling the PDO module:
but was failing with an error during the PDO configure:

```
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for Informix driver for PDO... yes, shared
configure: error: INFORMIXDIR environment variable is not set. Please use --with
-pdo-informix=<DIR> or set the INFORMIXDIR environment variable.
Removing intermediate container a73c9bfa211d
 ---> d86e02cc6801
Step 20/24 : COPY scripts/envvars.sh /tmp
```

I changed the script that builds the module so INFORMIXDIR is set before it runs the configure.

```
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20170718
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20170718
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate
 PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for Informix driver for PDO... yes, shared
checking for PDO includes... configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.
Removing intermediate container deee5a938a6e
```

Again it was failing somewhere else. Looking at the module build file, it expects the module in the following directories:

```
-- config.m4 --

  AC_MSG_CHECKING([for PDO includes])
  if test -f $abs_srcdir/include/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h; then
    pdo_inc_path=$abs_srcdir/ext
  elif test -f $abs_srcdir/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h; then
    pdo_inc_path=$abs_srcdir/ext
  elif test -f $prefix/include/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h; then
    pdo_inc_path=$prefix/include/php/ext
  else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.])
  fi
```

but in the IBM docker image, that file is in:

```
root@faf18c3c0ef5:/usr/include# find ./ -name php_pdo_driver.h
./php/20170718/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h
root@faf18c3c0ef5:/usr/include#
```

So I added a "ln -s" to the dockerfile to create the softlink.
These are the two files I altered are:

```
---install-informixpdo.sh ---
...
PDO_DIRECTORY=PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3
PDO_FILENAME=$PDO_DIRECTORY.tgz
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/ibm/informix
TMPDIR=/tmp
tar  -xvf $TMPDIR/$PDO_FILENAME  -C $TMPDIR/
cd  $TMPDIR/$PDO_DIRECTORY
phpize  &&  ./configure  && make  &&  make install

rm -r $TMPDIR/*
...
----------
```

and

```
--- dockerfile ---
....
ENV INFORMIXDIR /opt/ibm/informix
ENV PATH $INFORMIXDIR/bin:$PATH

COPY scripts/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3.tgz /tmp
COPY scripts/install-informixpdo.sh /tmp
RUN sudo ln -s /usr/include/php/20170718/ext /usr/include/php/ext
RUN sudo sh /tmp/install-informixpdo.sh

#Informix environment variables for Apache
COPY scripts/envvars.sh /tmp
...
-------------
```

With those changes I get the module compiled and installed when doing the "docker build" command

```
....
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /tmp/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/20170718/
Removing intermediate container 43bc22fb8234
 ---> 256d3fabdc70
Step 22/26 : COPY envvars.sh /tmp
....
```

PHP using with the apache config loads the module:

```
root@99d4150d07ed:/# php -c /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini -m | grep inform
ix
pdo_informix
root@99d4150d07ed:/#
```

And a simple connection, also appears to work without issues:

```
root@99d4150d07ed:/# cat t.php
<?php

$db = new PDO("informix:host=99d4150d07ed; service=9088;database=sysmaster; serv
er=informix; protocol=onsoctcp; EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "informix", "in4mix
");

print "Connection Established!</br></br>";

$stmt = $db->query("select * from systables");
$res = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
$rows = $res[0];
echo "Table contents: $rows.</br>";

?>
root@99d4150d07ed:/# php -c /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini t.php
Connection Established!</br></br>Table contents: systables.</br>root@99d4150d07e
d:/#
```

You could just add the softlink creation and the export INFORMIXDIR in the 'install-informixpdo.sh' file.

EDIT:

```
root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html# cat t.php
<?php
$db = new PDO("informix:host=".getenv('HOSTNAME')."; service=9088;database=sysmaster; server=informix; protocol=onsoctcp; EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "informix", "in4mix");

print "Connection Established!</br></br>";

$stmt = $db->query("select * from systables");
$res = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
$rows = $res[0];
echo "Table contents: $rows.</br>";

?>
root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html# php t.php
Connection Established!</br></br>Table contents: systables.</br>root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html#
root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html# curl http://localhost/t.php
Connection Established!</br></br>Table contents: systables.</br>root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html#
root@886a4870f1d0:/var/www/html#
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, make the mentioned changes and I do not get errors when doing the docker build but when doing `phpinfo()`, I do not see the extension enabled.
Update my `Github` repository so you can see the changes made.

Comment: Hello again, after reviewing I had the test code wrong and now I have the same result as you, my problem is that I do not see the extension pdo_informix enabled in the phpinfo ();

Comment: When I test the t.php file by apache, I have the error: `Excepcin capturada: could not find driver`

Comment: `root@3ba5c8519590:/etc/php/7.2/apache2# php -i | grep pdo
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_dblib.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_firebird.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_odbc.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
root@3ba5c8519590:/etc/php/7.2/apache2#`

Comment: I guess your php is picking the default php.ini and not the pdo.ini in the apache2 directory. That's the one where you are included  the "extension=pdo_....." clause. 
try running :

php -c /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini -m | grep inormix

Comment: I added "extension = pdo _informix.so" in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini which is the Loaded Configuration File, restart the apache service but continue without enabling the ext.

Comment: Hello again, run the line: `cp /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_informix.ini` and I have pdo_informix enabled when I run: `php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t html`, my question is, **how can I enable it to work in apache?**
Thanks for your time

Comment: See my edit above. I used your updated script and both php and apache can use the PDO driver. If pdo_informix shows in the output of 'php -m' it should be enabled everywhere.

Comment: hello, it still does not run pdo_informix in apache2 and when I run php -m | grep pdo_informix, the module is enabled. :(

Comment: check for errors in the /var/log/apache2 error log file.

Comment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_informix.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_informix.so (libifgls.so: cannot open shared object fi$
[Wed Aug 22 14:03:20.314277 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 484] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 22 14:03:20.314381 2018] [core:notice] [pid 484] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178557/discussion-between-jsagrera-and-andres).

Answer (score 0):

In `Dockerfile`, use `docker-php-ext-install` command to install `php` extension or module. If you use reguler `apt-get install` command, you should add step to enable it. See the example bellow, how to use the command:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget curl libxml2-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates \
    && wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
    && echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring iconv xml pdo_mysql phar zip \
```

`docker-php-ext-install` will install and enable the extension automatically. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding, I had already tried it in this way but I could not, because to realize the connection to informix it is necessary that the SDK Client of informix is also installed, that is why I am using the image directly from IBM that has informix already installed, I also had problems with that image to install the apache to recognize php.

I appreciate the answer but I see that you did not try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a container working inspired by [Joan Rivera's example](https://github.com/joanrivera/docker-informixpdo), from a `php:7.2-apache` image:
https://github.com/vctls/docker_php_pdo_informix

I just tested it successfully on a legacy Informix 7.2 database.

I got the Client SDK version 4.10 FC9DE for Linux x86-64 from [the IBM wbesite](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=ifxdl).
The setup is pretty straightforward once you've got your environment variables right.

I got a few warnings when compiling the PDO_Informix 1.3.3 PECL extension, but it works nonetheless.